How to find an unused variable in IDA?
I have a very simple program that declares a few variables and prints Hello!
I tried to find where the unused variables are stored in the IDA like I found the Hello! (by clicking the lea     rcx, _Format    ; "Hello!") but I couldn't find their name or anything.
The code is
#include <stdio.h>

// global variables
char my_char = 'b';
short my_short = 4000;
int my_int = 10;
long my_long = 65535;
double my_double = 4.32;

int main() {
    printf("Hello!");
    return 0;
}

I think theyr'e supposed to be in the .data but can't find it


C source code identifiers are not a part of the executable code, though they would be included in additional debug information for a debug build. Not finding those names in an executable is normal and to be expected,

@AviBerger is there a way to see where they're saved? Like within the IDA

What makes you think that unused variables will end up in the compiled binary?

@Siguza I have to read a book for school and one exercise in it says: "Define a collection of global variables of different types and watch where they are stored in memory" and I thought it meant they'll be somewhere in there. I'm new to this, so maybe I got wrong.

Possibilities 1) Being unused, they might be optimized out. 2) In at least some setups, they are initialized by the startup code, by copying their value into place from an area their initial values are stored. The startup code is code provided by the implementation that sets things up and then calls main(). So you could find and examine that code to try to locate them. 3) They could be setup to load directly into place, so you'd have to search for their binary values.

"Define a collection of global variables of different types and watch where they are stored in memory" doesn't say they are to be unused. You may be making this harder than it needs to be. Use them in main(). As long as those accesses are not optimized out, you can look at recovered code for main() to see where they are accessed from.

@AviBerger Can it be that the book is just old? Cause I had another problem that was caused by the age of the book.

Only thing I can think of in about this particular issue and the age of the book is that the likelihood of unneeded stuff getting optimized out of the code altogether is now higher.

@AviBerger is adding printf(my_int + my_double); to the main() will be considered using them inside the main()?

You'd want to use a correct printf call, like printf( "%f", my_int + my_double); or printf( "%d %f", my_int, my_double); otherwise, yes.

@AviBerger I found it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

I found that if the variable is not used it will not show in the data. For it to show I added code that utilities the variables in the main() and now it does show in the .data SEG in the IDA.
#include <stdio.h>

// global variables
char my_char = 'b';
short my_short = 4000;
int my_int = 10;
long my_long = 65535;
double my_double = 4.32;

int main() {
    printf("Hello!\n");

    printf("%c\n", my_char);
    printf("%d\n", my_short);
    printf("%d\n", my_int);
    printf("%ld\n", my_long);
    printf("%f\n", my_double);

    return 0;
}

